# PHP - Writing your own function VS using built-in functions

Tags: php, function, built-in

Are there any advantages using "box" functions, such as `array_map`, rather than writing your own loop (when you know that the "box" function can't be written in any other way than your own function?

(what for? sometimes it's more readable when the `callback` function is a custom one)

Comment: is this a question? an opinion? what?

Comment: I think it all depends on what you are doing.

Comment: @Rocket, as opposed to what you are not doing ??

Comment: @Dagon "when you know that the "box" function can't be written in any other way than your own function"

Comment: Does that mean when there is not a 'box' function to do what you want?

Comment: @Dagon I am not sure how can I get the question clearer than: "are there any advantages ...". Can you please clarify what is the part that I should clear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Built-in functions will always be faster vs the same implementation in PHP. The built-in function will execute in C, while the PHP function will be interpreted into C - then executed.

Comment: PHP code is interpreted always to C before execution? if so, i can assume that the built-in functions are already compiled?

Comment: @yossi yep - [take a look at the source for `array_map()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L4236)

Answer (score 2):

sometimes it is all about performances, since these functions might be coded in C language, low level, compared to php...

This is not systematic though.

Comment: Can you elaborate please about exceptions?

Comment: This is a safety assessment. I purely ignore which one could be not built in C, but since I don't know that all are, I prefer to mention a just in case possible exception. Odds are with us though, it doesn't affect the main idea that we should stick to the existing built-in versions of functions we need.